# OpenCV StereoRectifyUncalibrated to 3D Point Cloud

Tags: c++, opencv, stereo-3d

I have some code that works out all of the parts up to calculating values with cv::stereoRectifyUncalibrated. However, I am not sure where to go from there to get a 3D Point cloud from it.

I have code that works with the calibrated version that gives me a Q matrix and I then use that with reprojectImageTo3D and StereoBM to give me a point cloud.

I want to compare the results of the two different methods as sometimes I will not be able to calibrate the camera.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.martinperis.com/2012/01/3d-reconstruction-with-opencv-and-point.html I think this will be helpful. It has a code which converts Disparity Image to Point cloud using PCL and shows in 3D viewer.

Since you have Q, two images and other camera params(from calibration), you should use `ReprojectTo3D` to get depth map.

Use `StereoBM` or `stereoSGBM` to get Disparity Map and use that Disparit Map and Q to get depth image.

```
StereoBM sbm;
sbm.state->SADWindowSize = 9;
sbm.state->numberOfDisparities = 112;
sbm.state->preFilterSize = 5;
sbm.state->preFilterCap = 61;
sbm.state->minDisparity = -39;
sbm.state->textureThreshold = 507;
sbm.state->uniquenessRatio = 0;
sbm.state->speckleWindowSize = 0;
sbm.state->speckleRange = 8;
sbm.state->disp12MaxDiff = 1;

sbm(g1, g2, disp); // g1 and g2 are two gray images
reprojectImageTo3D(disp, Image3D, Q, true, CV_32F);
```

And that code basically converts depth map to Point cloud.

```
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr point_cloud_ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
 double px, py, pz;
 uchar pr, pg, pb;

 for (int i = 0; i < img_rgb.rows; i++)
 {
     uchar* rgb_ptr = img_rgb.ptr<uchar>(i);
     uchar* disp_ptr = img_disparity.ptr<uchar>(i);
     double* recons_ptr = recons3D.ptr<double>(i);
     for (int j = 0; j < img_rgb.cols; j++)
     {
         //Get 3D coordinates

          uchar d = disp_ptr[j];
          if ( d == 0 ) continue; //Discard bad pixels
          double pw = -1.0 * static_cast<double>(d) * Q32 + Q33; 
          px = static_cast<double>(j) + Q03;
          py = static_cast<double>(i) + Q13;
          pz = Q23;

          // Normalize the points
          px = px/pw;
          py = py/pw;
          pz = pz/pw;

          //Get RGB info
          pb = rgb_ptr[3*j];
          pg = rgb_ptr[3*j+1];
          pr = rgb_ptr[3*j+2];

          //Insert info into point cloud structure
          pcl::PointXYZRGB point;
          point.x = px;
          point.y = py;
          point.z = pz;
          uint32_t rgb = (static_cast<uint32_t>(pr) << 16 |
          static_cast<uint32_t>(pg) << 8 | static_cast<uint32_t>(pb));
          point.rgb = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&rgb);
          point_cloud_ptr->points.push_back (point);
    }
}

point_cloud_ptr->width = (int) point_cloud_ptr->points.size();
point_cloud_ptr->height = 1;

//Create visualizer
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer;
viewer = createVisualizer( point_cloud_ptr );
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Actually, that link has a code which converts OpenCV disparity map to PCL point cloud and shows in 3D.

Comment: The problem is that you have only given a link and in the event the link ever fails, this answer will become obsolete.  You should provide an overview of the link, code, etc here and include the link only as a reference.

Comment: In the uncalibrated case, he does *not* have the Q matrix, so this answer is not valid.